# Sonos - certificate - letsencrypt

Tags: ssl, certificate, lets-encrypt, sonos

I do not find the letsencrypt certificate in the trusted list published by Sonos (http://musicpartners.sonos.com/node/339 - CERTIFICATE AUTHORITIES TRUSTED BY SONOS PLAYERS).
Do you if Sonos supports the https://letsencrypt.org certificates even if they are not listed (yet)?

Thanks.

Comment: https://letsencrypt.org/docs/certificate-compatibility/

Answer (score 3):

Let's Encrypt is cross-signed by DST Root CA X3, who we trust (https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/), so it's OK to use it. We do have some partners that use Let's Encrypt.

Comment: I am using a Let's Encrypt certificate, but the self test is returning errors. I am wondering if there is anything I can do to make the test pass with a Let's Encrypt certificate.

Comment: What errors are you seeing in self test. That test sometimes provides false failures on SSL sections.

Comment: I'm getting these errors: A X.509_certificate element should be returned, indicating that [domain] has a valid X.509 certificate for the DNS name (expression is False); A notBefore and notAfter element should be returned, indicating that [domain] has a date range for validity; There was an exception while scanning the domain ([domain]) for secure session renegotiation: sslyze.utils.SSLyzeSSLConnection.SSLHandshakeRejected - TCP - Received RST; The partner domain [domain] must support at least one of the following TLS 1.0 cipher suites: AES128-SHA, AES256-SHA (expression is False)

Comment: Those are phantom errors. I've confirmed that the url works correctly. We'll be amending self test to make the ssl section more reliable.